# Allow ssh connections WITHOUT using openssh-server

Tags: ssh, lubuntu

I've got two Lubuntu (16.04.1 LTS) VMs on two different machines, and I'm running an application that is sending raw sockets. To make it easier on transferring the files in between computers, I set up `openssh-server` so that I could use `scp`. However, this messed up my program as I set the buffer at around 64 kB when, according to [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129543/does-openssh-have-a-maximum-packet-size), the maximum packet size is set to 32 kB. Therefore, I've uninstalled `openssh-server` from my VMs.

However, I can't connect over SSH anymore. The connection is always refused, and I've already gone into `ufw` to allow traffic on port 22 and ssh entirely. (By the way, `sudo ufw allow ssh` returns a "Skipping adding existing rule" output.

So, my question. I want to keep using `scp`, but without using `openssh-server`. How do I go about this? (Alternatively, I wouldn't mind reinstalling `openssh-server` so long as there was an option to expand the packet size in the config files.)

Comment: If you remote the `openssh-server`, you can't connect to that server using `ssh`. You changed maximum packet size in ssh server and recompiled? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve or what is the problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: For future readers, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87983/how-to-securely-allow-scp-but-not-ssh)